# difference between http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js and http://openlayers.org/dev/OpenLayers.js?

Tags: openlayers

When i use http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js as script tag in my js file, map is not showing and site is not working, but when i use http://openlayers.org/dev/OpenLayers.js its working fine,

previously it was working fine with  http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js. But now its not working. why?

Comment: Vague. have you checked your javascript console for errors? do you know the difference between the stable api and the development system? can you get a simple map to work with the /api version? etc etc.

Comment: it was working pretty fine before two days ago, now its not working. It is showing OpenLayers is not defined.